# Inverse Laplace Transform of exponential

Tags: laplace-transform

Is it possible to compute the inverse Laplace transform of:
$$\frac{1}{1-e^{-sa}}$$
where $a>0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is as follows.

$$\left( 1-{{\rm e}^{-sa}} \right) ^{-1}=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \left( {{\rm e}^{-sa}} \right) ^{n}
$$

Now, the inverse laplace transform of $e^{-nsa}$ is $Dirac(t-an)$.

Then we have

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\it Dirac} \left( t-an \right) $$
Do you agree?

Comment: Could you explain what do you do?

Comment: Are you confusing the delta Dirac function with the Heaviside step function?

Comment: I am using the Dirac function:  $$\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{{\rm e}^{-st}}{\it Dirac} \left( t-an \right) {d
t}={{\rm e}^{-san}}
$$

Comment: You are right :D