# Inverting Laplace Transform with Geometric Series: $\mathcal{L}C(t) = \frac{\mu e^{-\beta \tau}}{1-\mu e^{-\beta \tau}}$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, laplace-transform, inverse-function, geometric-series

**Question** Am I correctly resuming the series to invert this Laplace Transform? *Specific points of interest are bullet pointed.*

The Laplace Transform of a function, $C(t)$, is given by,

$$
F(\beta) = \mathcal{L}C(t) = \int_0^\infty C(t)e^{-\beta t}\,dt
$$
where, in this case,
$$
F(\beta) = \frac{\mu e^{-\beta \tau}}{1-\mu e^{-\beta \tau}} = \sum^\infty_{j=1} \mu^je^{-jt\beta}
\quad \text{for}\quad |\mu|<1
$$
and I expanded the geometric sum on the RHS. *This is valid as in my case, $\mu=\cos^2\tau$*

*Aside...*

To invert the Laplace Transformed form back to $C(t)$ I note that $\mathcal{L}\delta(t) = \int_0^{\infty}\delta(t)e^{-t\beta}dt=1$ and more generally that,
$$
\mathcal{L}\sum^\infty_{j=0}\mu^j\delta(t-j\tau) = \sum^\infty_{j=0}\mu^je^{-j\tau\beta}=\frac{1}{1-\mu e^{-\beta \tau}}
$$
*...End Aside*

- Is it valid to extend the argument to the summation starting at $j=1$?
  $$
  \mathcal{L}\sum^\infty_{j=1}\mu^j\delta(t-j\tau) \stackrel{?}{=} F(\beta) = \sum^\infty_{j=1} \mu^je^{-jt\beta}
  $$
  and hence,
  $$
  C(t) = \sum^\infty_{j=1}\mu^j\delta(t-j\tau)
  $$
- Should this be regarded similarly to an integral only accepting values $j=t/\tau$ for $t/\tau\ge1$?

If so this would give,
$$
C(t) = \mu^{t/\tau}
\quad \text{for}\quad t/\tau \in \mathbb{Z}^+
$$
by integrating over the delta function. As per the comments I would treat this as a numerical approximation for small $\tau$.

Comment: A related post http://math.stackexchange.com/q/937252/272850 that uses a similar method

Comment: I don't see what you want to say with $C(t) = \sum_{t = \tau}^\infty \mu^{t/\tau}$. (if $\tau > 0$) then you got that $C(t)$ is the distribution $\sum_{j=1}^\infty \mu^j \delta(t-j \tau)$ at this point there is nothing else to say (except that extending the inverse Laplace transform for distributions can be tricky)

Comment: and what I wrote is true only if you assume the domain of convergence is $Re(\beta) > \ln |\mu|$. Otherwise if the domain of convergence is $Re(\beta) < \ln|\mu|$ then the result is $C(t) = - \sum_{j=1}^\infty \mu^j \delta(t+j \tau)$

Comment: @user1952009 this represents an autocorrelation function so I require a form as a function of $t$ that can be numerically plotted to compare with data. I was not sure how to treat the delta function and so I am trying to somehow absorb it into the expression. This extra insight also implies that the sum must converge at $\beta=0$ to demand a finite integrated autocorrelation. I take it you are confirming my approach is fine for the shifted index of $j=1$. However, the issue of the delta function remains.

Comment: you can't. And the Laplace transform of $\delta(t)$ is well-defined and converges everywhere, in the same way the Laplace transform of your $C(t)$ is well-defined and converges whenever $Re(\beta)$ is large enough

Comment: If I take the limit such that $j$ approaches infinity for the scale defined by $t/\tau$ then I should be able to take the sum to an integral and then integrate out the delta function? (Also I've edited the sums as they should have vanished if I was treating it like an integral)

Comment: so you didn't read what I wrote. you can't simplify the sum of Dirac